# python-send-buffer (Emacs 24, Windows7)

Tags: python, emacs

I've been experimenting with Python a little bit under Emacs and when I have a buffer containing Python code I type C-c C-c to try and evaluate it.  What I get is:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'emacs' is not defined
```

What could I do to resolve this?  I've done a little bit of digging but sadly not been able to fix my issue.  In the *scratch* buffer I get the following output:

```
data-directory
"c:/emacs/emacs-24.0.90/etc/"

(getenv "PYTHONPATH")
nil
```

Which I presume is partly used to try and pick up emacs.py (which does exist in c:/emacs/emacs-24.0.90/etc/"

Any pointers greatly appreciated.